# different meaning of "like(conjunction)" in context

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

> [context]
>
> She caught a cold. So, she got a sick leave.
>
> He is dizzy now and asking a sick leave.

I come up with two possible answers below.

> Answer 1 : But it isn't the case like she got a cold. (the case means
>   just her getting a cold)
>
> Answer 2 : But it isn't the case like he seems to get discriminated.
>   (He can't get a sick leave and this seems like discrimination against
>   him)

But conjunction "like" means quite differenct in each case.

I'm worrying if I should have put a comma before 'like' to mean what each answer is supposed to mean.

**Is there any grammatical error, like missing comma, in both answers?**

or **is it only matter of interpretation to see conjunction "like" mean which?**

Comment: You give two answers, but what are the _questions_ you are answering? I would start with removig _the case_ anyway, because that's really too much. _It isn't like you need to add that to your sentence._

Comment: I was typing something similar to @oerkelens's comment. Using *the case like* in your Answer 1 and Answer 2 is dubious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"it isn't the case like..." is not meaningful English.

I think the idiom "it's not like ..." is what you are looking for.

> 1. But it's not like she's got the flu (she's only got a runny nose)
> 2. He's asking for leave, but it's not like they are going to give it to
>      him (it's unlikely)
>
> or
>
> 2. He feels like they are discriminating against him (he believes that...)

Comment: It may help to think of "like" as being an alternative for "as though"